# stratify sklearn train_test_split using dummy vector for 'stratify parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, training-data, imbalanced-data, test-data

I want to split my data into train, val, and test sets, using the `stratify` parameter in the `train_test_split` library.
I want to use a binary dummy vector (the vector name is `prop`) for the  `stratify` parameter, making the test's labels proportion the same as the binary vector proportion. However, it isn't working.

The code:

```
prop = np.zeros(len(y))
one_amount = round (0.012 * len(y))
prop[:one_amount] = 1


self.train_data.X, self.test_data.X, self.train_data.y, self.test_data.y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = (0.2) , random_state = 42, stratify= prop)

self.train_data.X, self.val_data.X, self.train_data.y, self.val_data.y = train_test_split(self.train_data.X, self.train_data.y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

The dummy vector I generated, and the new datasets labels' proportions are:

```
prop labels proportion 
class 0-  10988 ,  99.0 %
class 1-  133 ,  1.0 %
train data labels proportion 
class 0-  4989 ,  75.0 %
class 1-  1683 ,  25.0 %
val data labels proportion 
class 0-  1665 ,  75.0 %
class 1-  559 ,  25.0 %
test data labels proportion 
class 0-  1676 ,  75.0 %
class 1-  549 ,  25.0 %
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Stratify is used to balance the dataset, not to have class proportions as the input to the stratify parameter. Normally, you put in your targets into the Y parameter:

```
self.train_data.X, self.test_data.X, self.train_data.y, self.test_data.y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = (0.2) , random_state = 42, stratify=y)
```

I am not sure why you would want to make the class proportions so imbalanced as it would lead to a biased model and I am not sure how to do that.